# Não consigo salvar dados no database do Firebase - React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-database

Não consigo salvar dados no database do Firebase - React Native. Já fiz a instalação e o import do Firebase no projeto, o código esta assim:

```
 componentWillMount(){
  var config = {
    apiKey: "***************************",
    authDomain: "configuracaofirebase-3a6ef.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://configuracaofirebase-3a6ef.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "configuracaofirebase-3a6ef",
    storageBucket: "configuracaofirebase-3a6ef.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "939162871117"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

salvarDados(){
  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref("pontuacao").set("100");
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button 
        onPress={ () => { this.salvarDados() } }
        title="Salvar dados"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Salvar dados"
      />
      <Text>Meu App</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

O `componentWillMount` esta dando certo, só não funciona quando eu chamo o método `salvarDados`, aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poste o seu código, não fotos dele, fica mais fácil de entender o problema

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu código está no **componentWillMount()**. O seu component **App** não está sendo inicializado na sua função **render()**. Fazendo com que o **componentWillMount()** não seja executado.

Exemplo de inicialização do componente:

```
export default class App extends component {
  componentWillMount() { . . . }

  render() {
    <App />
  }
}
```

A solução para isso é você incluir o AppRegistry (pode ser depois da função render), então seu código vai passar pelo **componentWillMount()**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('<NomeDoProjeto>', () => App);
```

Caso não queira usar o AppRegistry, você pode incluir o codigo do firebase no seu construtor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  var config = { ... }
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo, continuou com o mesmo erro

Comment: colocando a inicialização do firebase no construtor também?

Comment: sim, é como se o comando firebase não estivesse ativo

Comment: esse é todo seu código?

Comment: Sim, eu fiz as importações da seguinte maneira:                              import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/auth';

Comment: to usando a versão 5.7.0 do firebase e a versão 0.57.7 do react-native

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver apenas adicionando um novo import.

Estava assim:
import firebase from '@firebase/app';

depois coloquei assim:
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/database';